# Change user agent string

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, user-agent

I want to change a USER AGENT string in Internet Explorer whilst it is running (or after launching). So I can't change through a registry key. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What for do you need it?

Comment: @Eugene Web UI testing application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fiddler tool is your friend here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

More details: http://www.fiddlertool.com/ua.aspx.

And if you are using IE8 there is an add-in to just change the UA string: http://www.enhanceie.com/ietoys/uapick.asp

Comment: I need to find solution in c#(or any other) programming language and embed to my application

Comment: Are you embedding IE in an application? You can't directly change the IE user agent but you should be able to add a "User-Agent" header to the http call that will overwrite the IE UA string.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Firefox, there is a User-Agent switcher add-on

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59

Comment: unfortunately, i cannt use firefox. only ie

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of IE, launch the developer tools (F12). From the menu, select **Tools** > **Change user agent string**, as shown below.

[image]